# Image is not uploaded to server from Android

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a image that captured by android camera to server, but the image is not saved.

**Android:**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
            encoded_string =android.util.Base64.encodeToString(array, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);

            String phpUrl = "http://192.168.43.104:80/dogCountingApp/newDog.php";
            URL url = new URL(phpUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpurlconnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpurlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpurlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputstream = httpurlconnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedwriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("encoded_string","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(encoded_string,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("image_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(image_name,"UTF-8");
            bufferedwriter.write(data);
            bufferedwriter.flush();
            bufferedwriter.close();
            outputstream.close();
```

**Php**

```
<?php
header('content-type : bitmap; charset = utf-8');

if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])){

$encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
$image_name = $_POST["image_name"];

$decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

$path = 'images/'.$image_name;

$file = fopen($path, 'wb');

fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
fclose($file);

}
?>
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php - what do those throw back?

Comment: You should let your php script echo() what happens. Then in your Android app you should read those echos. You are not doing these basic things. So you do not know what happens. And what does the logacat tell you? Any exceptions?